# Google Plus1 on mobiles. - How to disable annotation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-plus

I can't seem to disable annotations for the plus1 button on iPhone and Android. I tried:

```
<g:plusone size='tall' data-annotation='none'></g:plusone>"
```

as well as just

```
"annotation='none' "
```

Both work fine on desktops, but both show annotations on mobiles. Is this just me or are other having the same issues?

Example Link: http://filmandmusic.mobi/song/101

Answer (score 0):

Change it back to `<g:plusone size="tall" annotation="none"></g:plusone>`. I see the annotation on the desktop with `data-annotation`. If it still shows with annotations on mobile create a bug report. http://bugpl.us/new

Comment: Changed it back - makes no difference as per my initial post. Thanks for the bug report link.